# Do services require methods? Injection into controller failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an effort to keep my $rootScope clean, I am in need of an object that contains data that is shared among the controllers in my application. As defined, Services are the way to do this inside an Angular app.

With that being said, does a service require a method to be defined in order to work, or can it simply return a object with a list of properties that can be manipulated by the controllers?

Additionally, if the object returned by the service is just data, what is the best way to incorporate it into the scope. Below is my service definition:

```
angular.module('dataService', [])
.service('gameData', function() {
    this.loggedIn =  "false";
    this.gameJoined = "false";
    this.tableFull =  "false";
    this.username =  "";
    this.tableInfo =  {};
    this.gameNum =  null;
    this.atTable =  "";
    this.numJoined =  0;
    this.userNames =  [];
    this.numPlayers =  _.range(2,7);
    this.numOfRuns =  _.range(1,11);
});
```

And when I use this method to inject the service into the controller:

```
client.controller('loginController',  ['$scope','gameData', function
   ($rootScope, $scope, gameData) {
     $scope.gameData = gameData;
   console.log('gameData: ');
   console.log(gameData.loggedIn);
 }]);
```

gameData.loggedIn in is undefined when this runs.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Z

Comment: If **all** you are using a service for is storing values I would recommend using a value instead of a service. `.value('gameData', { ... })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service does not have to define a method, but if you simply want an object then consider using either `value(name, value)` or `constant(name, value)` to define a service that simply returns a value.

The difference between these two is that a constant may be injected into a module configuration function (a value cannot) and a value may be overridden by a decorator (which a constant cannot) but for a simple object to share data either will do the job.

```
angular.module('dataService', [])
.value('gameData', {
    loggedIn: false,
    gameJoined: false,
    tableFull: false,
    username: "",
    tableInfo: {},
    gameNum: null,
    atTable: "",
    numJoined: 0,
    userNames: [],
    numPlayers: _.range(2,7),
    numOfRuns: _.range(1,11)
});

client.controller('loginController', function($rootScope, $scope, gameData) {
     $scope.gameData = gameData;
   console.log('gameData: ');
   console.log(gameData.loggedIn);
 });
```

Comment: If I use this method, how do I have it interact with the expressions?

Comment: I've edited to show how your code might look as an example. Note that if you need expressions that depend on injecting other constants, values, or services you will have to do what you originally tried and create a service with no methods.

Answer (score 2):

No, methods are not compulsory in services. The reason you're code isn't working is because you have messed up the dependancies in the controller.

Change:

```
['$scope','gameData', function
   ($rootScope, $scope, gameData)
```

to

```
['$rootScope', '$scope','gameData', function
   ($rootScope, $scope, gameData)
```

Comment: To avoid this sort of injection problem in future I would suggest the OP look at using `gulp` with `gulp-ng-annotate` or a similar toolchain. Then the source code can just use plain functions with all the annotations added automatically.

Comment: You can also use `ng-strict-di`: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi